# Using User Input as a Where Clause in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a requirement where I need to apply some aggregate functions and filter the values based on some user input
Take a look at the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import tensorflow

donor_age = input("Enter Donor's Age: ")
donor_organ = input("Enter Organ to Donate: ")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Probability.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book
df_success_rates = pd.read_excel('HealthChain.xlsx')

df_total=df_success_rates.groupby(['Donor_Age','Donor_Gender','Donor_Organ','SuccessfullCompletion'])\
    .size().to_frame('total_count').reset_index().sort_values(['Donor_Age', 'total_count'], ascending=True)
df_total['Total_Operations']=df_total.groupby(['Donor_Age','Donor_Gender','Donor_Organ']).total_count.transform(np.sum)

df_total['Probability']=df_total['total_count']/df_total['Total_Operations']
#df_total=df_total[(df_total.Donor_Age == donor_age)]
df_total.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Prob', engine='xlsxwriter', index=False)

writer.save()
workbook.close()
```

Everything works well but when the complier reads the line

```
df_total=df_total[(df_total.Donor_Age == donor_age)]
```

it throws an error stating 
[image]

But when the donor's age is hardcoded, the code runs well.

Any idea what could be the reason for the issue and the fix for the same

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Is the dtype of Donor_Age `str` or numeric? If numeric you need to cast the type of `donor_age` as `str` is default type from `input`

Comment: Yes it worked..thanks Ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
donor_age = int(input("Enter Donor's Age: "))
```

input() returns a string, it looks like you are comapring a string with a int which can't be compared. Either cast the input to a int or float or cast the other age as a str.

Comment: yes did the same..also for the string input I had to follow the same process. Thanks!